# Save data of an increasing dictionary in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save the data of an API response in my django tables but the problem that I am facing is that the API responds in a list which consists of several dictionaries and the number of dictionaries increase everytime i call the api.

Example
On 1st call

```
A = [{foo:4,
      bar:5}]
```

On 2nd call

```
A = [{foo:4,
      bar:5}, {foo:8, bar:10}]
```

On 3rd call

```
A = [{foo:4,
      bar:5}, {foo:8, bar:10}, {foo:12, bar:15}]
```

and so on

My model looks like this:

```
class Tracking(models.Model):

    foo = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
```

My views.py

```
class trackapi(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk):

       response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, data=payload, auth=user_pass)

       for i in response.text:
           Tracking.objects.create(foo = i["foo"], bar = i["bar"]
```

But this will create a lot of multiple enteries in the tables, how should I do this such that data in my table is not replicated ?

What I tried:

```
    lr_id = LR.objects.filter(lr_quiz=pk)[0].id
    invoice_id = Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_quiz=pk)[0].id

    for i in track_response:

        Tracking.objects.get_or_create(lr_no=lr_id,invoice_no=invoice_id,
                                       tracking_id=i["_id"],trip_id = i["tripId"],telephone=i["tel"],
                                       loc = i["loc"], address=i["address"],city=i["city"],
                                       created_at=i["createdAt"])
```

api data:

```
[{"_id":"5dccedadff47e867a2833819","tel":"xxxxxxx","loc":[28.498692,77.095215],"tripId":"5dccedaaff47e867a28337ec","mode":"automated","osm_data":{"distance_remained":10791,"time_remained":1649.5},"distance_remained":10870,"time_remained":1173,"curr_ETA":"2019-11-14T06:43:19.664Z","address":"100,
The National Media Centre, Sector 24, Gurugram, Haryana 122022,
India","city":"Gurugram","createdAt":"2019-11-14T06:01:17.166Z"},{"_id":"5dccedacff47e867a2833801","tel":"xxxxxxx","loc":[28.498692,77.095215],"tripId":"5dccedaaff47e867a28337ec","mode":"automated","osm_data":{"distance_remained":10791,"time_remained":1649.5},"distance_remained":10870,"time_remained":1173,"curr_ETA":"2019-11-14T06:43:18.459Z","address":"100,
The National Media Centre, Sector 24, Gurugram, Haryana 122022,
India","city":"Gurugram","createdAt":"2019-11-14T06:01:16.163Z"}]
```

Comment: https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create  These docs will help you.

Comment: It looks like the entries actually have all we need! The `_id` field can be used as the primary key for each object, meaning you don't even have to treat it like a stack, and even if the order/composition of the data set changes, you can still avoid duplication.

Comment: @th0nk- Okay so I should just use "_id" in the get_or_create ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, it has been updated with this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @drd's answer may function, I think there might be a better way that takes advantage of Django's extensive tooling.

With very simple dictionaries such as the `foo` and `bar` ones used in your example, it's difficult to use the following method, but I doubt your data is that simple.

So, you can use the wonderful `get_or_create` method! From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

> A convenience method for looking up an object with the given kwargs (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one if necessary.
>
> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.
>
> This is meant to prevent duplicate objects from being created when requests are made in parallel, and as a shortcut to boilerplatish code.

But, in order to ensure that this works properly, since this is a bit of an edge case, you'll need to get a bit hacky with it.

Assuming the data set returned by the API is comparable to a stack structure, you could design a handler that gives each entry an ID based on where it appears in the data set returned by the API, i.e. first dict is 1, second is 2, etc.

`models.py`

```
class Tracking(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField("ID", max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

`views.py`

```
def get(...):    
...
# we also need to deserialize the response data into an iterable list
data = json.loads(response.text)

for i, entry in enumerate(data):
    Tracking.objects.get_or_create(pk=i, **entry)
```

This will create new objects as they come, without cluttering your database with the repeated stuff from earlier calls.

**EDIT**

If the data being grabbed from the API already has some sort of unique field (in this case, `_id`), you can just use that value as the primary key, like this:

`views.py`

```
def get(...):
    ...
    for entry in data:
        pk = entry.pop("_id")
        Tracking.objects.get_or_create(pk=pk, **entry)
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting  type error `TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried and test data

Comment: Oh right - I used some shorthand. The data from `response` needs to be de-serialized and made into a dictionary, will update the answer.

Comment: Please have a look, I have updated the question with data and what I tried

Comment: Getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" now

Comment: When are you seeing that? Could you include the full stack trace?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Rahul\PycharmProjects\classroom\views\classroom.py", line 782, in get
    tracking_id=i["_id"],trip_id = i["tripId"],telephone=i["tel"],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
Would that be enough ?

Comment: I see. If you're going to simply iterate through the list of dictionaries and grab each dictionary, you have to follow the loop construct that is written in the second example, that was added in the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202314/discussion-between-th0nk-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: I should use tracking_id = i.pop("_id"), trip_id = i.pop("tripId") ?

Comment: *Discussion moved to chat*

Answer (score 0):

Use
What should not be duplicated? 
Is it only foo or only bar? or both taken together?

I guess both taken together, by your example. Use **unique_together**, it will throw exception while adding duplicates, handle it to ignore or log it for future referece.

```
class Tracking(models.Model):

    foo = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('foo', 'bar')
```